# How can i convert from "STL" format to "3DS"

Tags: c++, matlab, opengl, 3d

Is there any way to convert an [STL 3D object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) to a [3ds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds) one by matlab code or C++

Comment: Ah, I see!  In the context of C++, "STL" usually means [something quite different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)...

Answer (score 3):

[AssImp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/).  [Import formats](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) and [output formats](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_export.html).

Answer (score 0):

c ++ language you can refer to lib3ds. Maybe you can think about the OpenSceneGraph's osgDB plugin. It deal with the stl format and 3ds format.